# Grails Config File per Environment

Tags: grails, groovy

I would like to make a single Config File for every Environment, so I added to `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "file:conf/${InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()}.groovy",
    "classpath:${Environment.current.name}.groovy"
]
```

this work fine locally, but while building an WAR File with `war  -Dgrails.env=stage` it doesn't work. I am using Grails 2.5.6.

How can I exclude the Environment Configs in a single File?

Comment: When you build with war  -Dgrails.env=stage there is an error during the build, on there is an error when you deploy this war in the stage environment ? also you want a single config file per environment but in your line classpath you specify a file name depending on the environment (Environment.current.name)

Comment: You need to mention application running environment ( development / production / testing ), you may keep external config file same for every environment ( if the content is same or put variable to check environment and pick config inside the config file......You can refer answer here.......  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46460845/how-to-load-datasource-configuration-from-external-file-in-grails-3-1-8/46464697#46464697